# mootools mouseevent targets

Tags: javascript, dom, mootools

whats is the difference between a "target" a "relatedTarget" and a "fromelement" in terms of a mootools mouse event?

for example in the following code why is target not being used and why is there a || involved?

```
'mouseenter':function(e){
var reltar = e.relatedTarget || e.fromElement;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically,

The **`target`** is the element the event is dispatching on. i.e.

```
$('el').addEvent('mouseenter',function(event){
    console.log(event.target) //target refers to the 'el' element.
}
```

The **`relatedTarget`** is the element the mouse came from in case of mouseover/enter.

**`fromelement`** is the MS way to implement what **`relatedTarget`** does. Therefore,

```
var reltar = e.relatedTarget || e.fromElement;
```

is a cross-browser way to detect what element the mouse came from.

Answer (score 1):

W3C says that **`event.relatedTarget`** is the element where mouse *comes from* in a `mouseover` event, or the element that the mouse *goes to* in a `mouseout` event.

However, IE uses two separate properties for those two cases: **`event.fromElement`** is the element the mouse *comes from* in a `mouseover` event, while **`event.toElement`** is the element the mouse *goes to* in a `mouseout` event.

You can find more details and some examples on the following page by Peter-Paul Koch (very good content there):

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_mouse.html